# Awesome TM gnome-screensaver lockscreen command not working

Tags: gnome, awesome, screen-lock

My friend recently introduced me to the Awesome tiling window manager. I was trying to manipulate the **rc.lua** to configure it to my liking. Can someone tell me why this command doesn't take effect:

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Control" }, "l", function () awful.util.spawn("gnome-screensaver-command -l") end),
```

The command on the terminal works.

Since I use Linux Mint Cinnamon, I also tried the **`cinnamon-screensaver-command`** on the terminal and it works. The lua object ( I suppose) to which I added my config looks like the following:

```
clientkeys = awful.util.table.join(
    awful.key({ modkey, "Control" }, "l", function () awful.util.spawn("cinnamon-screensaver-command -l") end),
    awful.key({ modkey,           }, "f",      function (c) c.fullscreen = not c.fullscreen  end),
    awful.key({ modkey, "Shift"   }, "c",      function (c) c:kill()                         end),
    awful.key({ modkey, "Control" }, "space",  awful.client.floating.toggle                     ),
    awful.key({ modkey, "Control" }, "Return", function (c) c:swap(awful.client.getmaster()) end),
    awful.key({ modkey,           }, "o",      awful.client.movetoscreen                        ),
    awful.key({ modkey,           }, "t",      function (c) c.ontop = not c.ontop            end),
    awful.key({ modkey,           }, "n",
        function (c)
            -- The client currently has the input focus, so it cannot be
            -- minimized, since minimized clients can't have the focus.
            c.minimized = true
        end),
    awful.key({ modkey,           }, "m",
        function (c)
            c.maximized_horizontal = not c.maximized_horizontal
            c.maximized_vertical   = not c.maximized_vertical
        end)
)
```

Thanks

Comment: And how does your rc.lua looks like?

Comment: @grochmal Do you think I added it to the right part of the file?

Comment: I do not use awesome but i'd bet on a PATH issue, just like g33kz0r argues.  I'd try `awful.util.spawn_with_shell` instead of `awful.util.spawn`.  Second, i'd also try to add it to `globalkeys` instead of `clientkeys` (my knowledge on awesome is limited but i always believed that keybindings go into `globalkeys`)

Comment: To ensure this is a specific problem with gnome-screensaver-command, try debugging by replacing it with bash script that writes into another file

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you reloaded awesome?

You might want to try: https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/modules/awful.util.html#spawn_with_shell

Or put something else in `spawn` to ensure your command is being run.

Also, is `gnome-screensaver-command` in your path?

Comment: I tried spawn and spawn_with_shell as well as tried executing evince with the same key pattern. Doesn't seem to work. Have I added this to the wrong part of the file?

Comment: Which keys are you pressing?  (should be Ctrl+Alt+l)